# Handling Lazy loading with webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying test a single page web application with webdriver in page object model using C#. The website javascript intensive and does Lazy loading
i have tried using Explicit wait and used the following code to check if the javascript is active

```
return jQuery.active == 0
```

I have tried using a combination of both to know if the page has loaded

```
WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));
    bool WhenToExit = true;
            while (WhenToExit) // Handle timeout somewhere
            {
                var ajaxIsComplete = (bool)(Browser.Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
                if (ajaxIsComplete)
                {


                    bool isDisplayed = _wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.ClassName("example"))).Displayed;

                    if(isDisplayed)
                    {
                    break;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                int Timer = 0;
                Timer++;
                if (Timer == 100)
                {
                    WhenToExit = false;
                }
            }
```

.But still the webdriver does not wait for the page to load , it just keeps executing the steps ,So i have been forced to use Thread.Sleep(), which i dont want use and its not good practices.
 
Can some tell me how to Get around this issue,Thank u in advance

Comment: Well how do you know when the page is 'complete'? I.e what shows on the screen to tell you this? Your explicit wait is incorrect. It is going to wait until it's found in the DOM but not until it's displayed.

Comment: how did you initialize the WebDriverWait i.e. your _wait object? Is the timeout in it sufficient enough for webdriver to keep on polling for elements to appear?

Comment: @Arran i think the displayed function will wait for the element to displayed in page ,before it returns the value true or false . I have posted the updated code<br>@nilesh the wait time is sufficient i have updated the code thank you in advance